# Trigger Controller Method using Hangfire for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, hangfire

Good day guys,

I'm trying to trigger a certain command inside my `Controller` in ASP.NET Core.

I've installed hangfire and configured my `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage('my conn string'));
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    // add hangfire
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    app.UseHangfireServer();    
    ...
}
```

But the problem is, my sample controller has multiple dependency injections

```
public class ProductsController: Controller
{
    private readonly ISomething1 something1;
    private readonly ISomething2 something2;
    private readonly ISomething3 something3;

    public ProductsController(ISomething1 something1, ISomething2 something2, ISomething3 something3){
        this.something1 = something1;
        this.something2 = something2;
        this.something3 = something3;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> TriggerMe(){
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement something like this on my startup

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
() => // trigger the TriggerMe() controller method ,
Cron.Daily);
```

Any help please? Thank you

Comment: As it's a controller method, I'd say the best thing to do here is to actually invoke it via HTTP rather than programatically because then you're leaving the framework do what it should be doing with pipelines and error handling.

Comment: But I need to trigger that Controller Method. to generate my PDF since I'm using Rotativa to generate pdf byte.

Comment: what is the purpose of a cron job here then? because Rotavita is specific for generating PDFs from Razor views

Comment: My controller method returns a pdf file using rotativa, that's why I need to trigger it using hangerfire automatically. Using rotativa in a normal class won't work since it needs ControllerContext

Comment: I get that, but why trigger PDF generation from hangfire?

Comment: To send pdf to email. Using Rotativa, there's a way where you can build byte from `ViewAsPdf` and that byte will be send automatically to the recipient's email.

Comment: by triggering PDF generation from a cron job, to whom do you want to return generated PDF?
As when an HTTP request is received we have the connection of the client to whom we want to return a response.

Comment: That's why I need to trigger that controller method without requesting the HTTP. In my controller method, it can return bytes and that byte will be send to email

Comment: By using HTTP you will be triggering the controller method, just like you do when you hit an endpoint of your API.

Comment: so for sending view content in email, wouldn't you prefer `HTML` instead of PDF?

Comment: PDF is more convenient than `HTML` of course. Especially for reporting purposes.

Comment: updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can call methods specified in a controller like this. Specify the type of your controller in AddOrUpdate Method. This way you can access any method in a class including controller your case.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<HangfireController>("jobId_1", (hfController) => hfController.MethodInYourController(), Cron.Minutely);
```

Answer (score 0):

I triggered my jobs like this but I generally trigger service methods on service's interface. I think you can do it controller with same way. You can try like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ProductsController>("myTriggerMeJob", x => x.TriggerMe(), Cron.Daily);
```

If you face a problem, you can write.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE** 
As the Rotavita is tightly coupled with controllers,views etc. I'd recommend solving this problem in two steps

1. Generate HTML from a view (for reporting/email purposes separate out that view from normal ones) using [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine), you'd only need the view/template path and the model (containing values to be rendered)
2. Use the HTML to generate a PDF using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) (`Rotavita` uses this lib under the hood)

**Original**

As invoking a `controller` instance is a process done by the framework and it shouldn't be invoked or called by cron jobs.
For your problem, you just need to add the reference to the method or delegate. Assuming that you're going to move your code to some other class.

```
var instance=new Foo();
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => instance.DoSomething,Cron.Daily);
```

and the `Foo` class

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
    //your code
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't get my question

Comment: It's a Controller class with multiple dependency injections

Comment: There's no problem with normal class, but the problem is when you have controller class with dependency injecitons

Comment: as I said, something like that shouldn't be done by cron jobs

Comment: "something like that shouldn't be done by cron jobs" - why not?

Comment: that id an old comment, controller instance gets created by the framework itself, there are a lot of things involved before controller instance creation that we shouldn't be doing manually so using `Rotavita` or meddling with controllers shouldn't be done in cron jobs. 
in principle cron jobs are responsible for actions independent of user input like an HTTP request

Comment: you should use the approach given in updated section of the answer